# Not able to distinguish between hidden cells and others. Using POI 3.8 and xls/xlsx format

Tags: java, apache-poi

Not able to distinguish between hidden cells and others. Using POI 3.8 and xls/xlsx format. baseRow.getZeroHeight(), baseCell.getCellStyle().getHidden(), baseSheetX.getColumnStyle(14).getHidden() all return false though entire column is hidden. Please guide.

Comment: Did you try fresh POI 3.10?

Comment: Not yet. Will try today and let you know.

Comment: tried on POI 3.9. But no luck.

Comment: 3.10 is beta. Can't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entire column is hidden, Excel will just mark the column itself as hidden on the sheet.  It won't go through that particular column index in all rows and change the cell styling just to make all the cells hidden, and it won't go through the column cell style either.

Try the method [`Sheet#isColumnHidden(int)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#isColumnHidden%28int%29).

> Get the hidden state for a given column